# Не работает выдача qr кодов discord.py

Tags: python, discord

```
@client.command()
async def qrcode (ctx, v:int):
    nnn = qrcode.make (v)
    await ctx.send(f'{nnn}d')
```

Не отправляет изображение.

Comment: Возможно, проблема в том, что у вас библиотека и функция бота называются одинаково